# In Neo4j ,how to find if graph is one connected or multiple disjoint

Tags: java, neo4j

I have created a graph using neo4j Java API for the below dataset .

Paper  : Cited Papers

Paper1:[Paper2,Paper3,Paper4]

Paper2:[Paper3,Paper1]

Paper3:[Paper4]

Paper4:[]

Paper5:[Paper6]

Paper6:[]

PseudoCode for graph creation

```
GraphDatabaseService graph;
IndexManager idx;

//In a for loop
 Node node = idx.get(""); // For each Paper
 if(node == null) {
   node = graph.createNode();
   idx.add(node);
 }     
  node.createRelationship(); // For cited Papers
```

After the above step how can I find form Neo4j API that all nodes(papers) are connected or not.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, what you try to achieve is called "connected component" computation, and some approaches are described here: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_%28graph_theory%29).

You should be able to do what you want with a simple traversal. The Neo4j Traversal framework is described here: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorial-traversal.html.